# Should empty "if" statement in C# lead to an error or warning?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

Let me start from a real life example:

> Customer: 
>   Alex, just noticed something strange in the RemovalProcessor at line 138:
>
> ```
> if (Session.Handler.ExecutePrefetchTasks()==null); 
>   Session.ExecuteDelayedQueries();
> ```
>
> Should the semicolumn behind the 'if' be there?
>
> Me: 
>   Oops... I'll send this to our guys to check, but most likely, you're right.

Although the case is rare, I admit nearly any big project has similar issue.

I understand that semicolon (and statement block) usage rules in C# can't be changed (personally I'd prefer Python style). But I think it's a good idea to identify *exactly this* case with `if` statement, and classify it as an error or warning.

Few Q/A I have in mind:

- **Why warning or error should be generated in this case?**

  Because it's a developer's mistake with may be 99% probability.
- **Why error is preferable in this case?**

  In many cases warnings are ignored by developers.

  I understand this is their own problem, and there is /warnaserror 
  (threat warnings as errors) switch, but since this is an error
  with very high probability, and, if it isn't an error (really? ;) ),
  it's quite easy to fix this, may be it's better to classify this case
  as an error.

  Finally, error in this case won't "restrict" the developer, 
  since such code can (and likely, must) always be rewritten 
  without `if` statement.
- **Why warning is preferable in this case?**

  This won't break the compatibility; I also suspect some code generators
  may generate code relying on the current behavior.

So I'd be glad to hear your opinions about this.

Comment: Resharper will give you a warning :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It already produces a warning:

> [Possible mistaken empty statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x19t380(VS.90).aspx)

I agree with you that an error would have been preferable (if you really want an empty statement, can always write it as `{ }`, which is more explicit) — but they are not going to change the C# language in this way. It would be a breaking change, and I suspect their (read: Eric Lippert’s) justification will be “the benefit doesn’t outweigh the cost”.

Comment: Great - it seems I also didn't notice this.

Comment: Concerning Eric Lippert’s justification - probably. But after finding out (here) that I missed this warning by my own (as well as at least few more developers @ our team), I'd also vote for error.

Comment: @Alex: Does this indicate that your project has too many warnings, so everybody is ignoring them? Maybe you should consider fixing the code so that it doesn’t have warnings anymore and/or use `#pragma warning disable` in places where you think the code is fine and the warning should be silenced. Then you can start paying attention to the warnings again.

Comment: @ Timwi: no, actually, there are just several ones for each project. But since most of unfixed warnings are not really important, it seems now we look up them rarely.

Comment: You guys know that you can turn on the "all warnings are errors", switch, right?

Comment: @Alex Yakunin: That is exactly what I meant. If you have so many warnings that you ignore them all, then *you should be worried*. Go through the warnings *as soon as possible* (otherwise you’ll only get more and more) and for each warning, either change the code or add a `#pragma warning disable`.

Comment: @Eric: thanks - yes, it was mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This example, similar to yours, should not produce a compile error because it has the purpose to execute logic conditionally.

```
if ( DoSomething() || SolveEquation() ) ;  // Intentional - compiles and  runs as expected.
```

If the `if` keyword is removed you will get a compile error.

```
DoSomething() || SolveEquation();  // Compile ERROR.
```

[Short circuit logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(VS.71).aspx) of C# determines: if DoSomething() returns `true` then SolveEquation() is not evaluated; otherwise it is evaluated.

We'll hypothesize that both functions change the state of the running program in some way, so it's important which one is executed - because that will determine a specific kind of program state. Of course the better way to write it would be...

```
if ( ! DoSomething() )
    SolveEquation();
```

or (Thanks [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106042/) for this one from the comments)

```
bool result = DoSomething() || SolveEquation();
```

.. but why rob the user of the first way?

Because the first way can be argued to be bad form, but it proves you don't necessarily want the situation to produce a compile error.

**This is my argument that it should not produce a compile error**. The existing warning is good just in case the developer made a common mistake.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to use `bool result = DoSomething() || SolveEquation();` in this case.

Comment: Hey @Alex thanks for that one. Added it to the answer with credit.