# Absence of if / loop body allowed: example?

Tags: java

I found a few weird constructs in Java that the compiler allows, but for which I'm not sure what could be the practical use.

1) if statement:

```
if((score=score+10) > 110); //No if body
```

while eg: `switch(++i);` is not

2) for loop:

```
for(;;); //No loop body
```

Are there practical, valid circumstances to use the preceding code?

Comment: it's usually only useful if there are side effects of the expressions within the statements

Comment: Useful or not, question is too-broad. And opinion-based.

Comment: I was just looking for an example where the code could be useful. I'll delete the question if you think it adds no value.

Comment: I have used `while` loops without bodies to completely consume an iterator or `InputStream`.

Comment: @Tunaki well, if you say it is opinion based, I opine that `for(;;);` brings me cakes!

Comment: @mihi but OP's code literally does nothing - the `for` loop has no body

Comment: @Shadowfax Really? It brings waffles for me!

Comment: If you wait long enough, and look in enough places, quantum theory says that a unicorn will appear

Comment: @Tunaki Not such a stupid question so it seems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428903/empty-if-statements It does appear to be a duplicate though. Also a great example of the SO bandwagon, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Where did I say this was a stupid question really? Because I didn't. I said "Too broad and opinion-based". Which is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if((score=score+10) > 110);
```

is equivalent to:

```
score += 10;
```

but has no practical use otherwise.

---

This:

```
for(;;);
```

loops forever doing nothing - not particularly useful, unless you wanted to create a permanently busy thread perhaps for testing purposes.

Comment: You're wrong. for(;;) is the equivalent to while(true) and there are PLENTY of uses for using that.

Comment: @LukeXu Except that if you mean "while true" why not say `while(true)`?

Comment: @Luke `for(;;);` (empty body as per OP Q) it is equivalent to `while(true);` (empty body). No use.

Comment: @LukeXu FYI, before you judge someone as wrong (especially a high-rep user), there is PLENTY of difference between `for(;;)` and `for(;;);`, which, as said here already, has **no use**.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ FYI, before you judge perhaps you should look at the edit history and then look at the time stamps of the comments. I didn't know reputation made you a good coder.

Comment: @LukeXu Apologies, I didn't look at the edit history. But still, I think the initial version was just the result of a typo, not the intention of the answerer. You are right, reputation doesn't make you a good coder, but in most of the cases only good coders make good reputations. I am sure you will agree :-)